# Webhook Post URL is not getting called when we do subscribe or unsubscribe in Mailchimp c# asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net, mailchimp

I created one endpoint using C# asp.net web API and I provided this endpoint URL as web hook URL in Mailchimp to receive subscribe or unsubscribe events form Mailchimp, but when I subscribe or unsubscribe in mailchimp, the web hook post URL is not getting called.

The following is the endpoint defined using C# asp.net web API.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("MCCallBackAPI4")]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] string data)
{
    //TODO code to sync with our DB
    return Ok();

}
```

Can somebody help here to get the events from Mailchimp?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.